# Inline select when inserting data using Django's ORM model

Tags: python, django, django-models, sql-insert

I'm currently trying to optimize the following piece of code which is called very frequently in my current project

```
Hit(link     = self.link,
    ip       = self.request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'],
    referrer = self.request.META['HTTP_REFERER'],
    country  = Country.objects.filter(shorthand=country_code).get()
).save()
```

which generates the following SQL query (SQLite backend, for testing purposes):

```
SELECT * FROM "ucp_country" WHERE "ucp_country"."shorthand" = 'DE';
INSERT INTO "ucp_hit" ("link_id", "ip", "referrer", "country_id")
VALUES (1, '127.0.0.1', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/ucp/manage_links', 83);
```

where `DE` is the country-code and `83` it's ID, returned by the SELECT query.

Is there some way to tell Django to merge the queries into a single one? I'm aware of the exception that occurs when an unknown country code is passed, the posted code is only there for explanatory purposes of the problem. I'm thinking of something like:

```
INSERT INTO "ucp_hit" ("link_id", "ip", "referrer", "country_id")
VALUES (1, '127.0.0.1', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/ucp/manage_links',
        (SELECT "id" FROM "ucp_country" WHERE "ucp_country"."shorthand" = 'DE'));
```

In case the requested country can not be found, the query would be supposed to insert `NULL`. Is it possible to tell Django to generate such a query in some way?

Comment: I am not sure this kind of optimization will drastically improve performance. If you are sure it's a bottleneck, why not loading the entire country table in memory?

Comment: I already considered doing that, however I was curious if there is a way to archive it the way I posted it.